# continuous surjective function from $n$-sphere to unit interval

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $S^n:=\{x \in \mathbb R^{n+1} : ||x||=1\}$ . Let $f : S^n \to [0,1]$ be a continuous surjective function , then is it necessarily true that $f^{-1}\{x\}$ is infinite $ \forall x \in [0,1]$ ?

Comment: What is your mean by "infinite"?

Comment: @C.F.G: What do you mean ? Infinite set of course ...

Comment: @LucyferZedd Which contest are you talking about?

Comment: @RobertZ https://brilliant.org/wiki/tessellate-stems/

Comment: @LucyferZedd I deleted my answer. Please let me know when the contest is over.

Comment: @RobertZ It will be over by tomorrow. Thanks for deleting your answer.

Comment: Can't really imagine this being used in a serious contest. May be if you have a dozen questions, and this is to weed out the weakest? Ok, a natural follow-up question would be a bit more interesting.

Comment: @RobertZ The contest is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $f(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1})=\frac{x_1+1}2$. Then $f^{-1}(1)=\{(1,0,0,\ldots,0)\}$.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true. Take a point $x_0\in S^n$, and consider the continuous map $f(x):=\frac{1}{2}\|x-x_0\|$. Then, for any $x\in S^n$,
$$0\leq f(x)\leq \frac{\|x\|+\|x_0\|}{2}\leq 1.$$
Moreover $f(-x_0)=\|x_0\|=1$ and $f^{-1}(0)=\{x_0\}$.